# I want to make my discord bot be able to reply to a command with a username with a link that contains the inputted username

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want the user to input **!fn maxtl** and the bot would reply by putting out this link
https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/maxtl/event

This is what I am thinking it would look like. Can someone provide me with any suggestions on how to improve this Discord bot API usage?

```
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === `!fn ${Username}`) {
    msg.reply(`https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/${Username}/events`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: ```js
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === `!fn ${Username}`) {
    msg.reply(`https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/${Username}/events`);
  }
});
```

Comment: for using the variable interpolation you need to use backticks ` (same as tilde button) instead of quotes

Comment: oh sorry i messed up that formatting thank you for the note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't doing any other processing of the message, this is what you'll probably need to do.

```
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith('!')) return;

  const arguments = msg.content.split(' ');
  const command = arguments.shift();

  if (command === '!fn') {
    msg.reply(`https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/${arguments[0]}/events`);
  }
});
```

This will

1. Check and see that the message begins with your command identifier (assuming it's "!")
2. Split the message in to an array of arguments;
3. Remove and store the command in a command variable
4. Check to see if the command is equal to "!fn"
5. Reply with a url that includes argument[0] which at this point would be equal to the username if one was provided.

Comment: Nice, this is far more generic than mine and can handle the commands without knowing the userName beforehand! I will upvote when I get them refreshed later!

Answer (score 0):

I think this block of code is something you are looking for, I am not 100% because I don't know what the rest of your bot is doing.

This code will

1. Listen for a message
2. The bailout of the code execution if the message doesn't start with !fn
3. Attempts to find the message with mentioned Username (your snippet shows this variable
   available so I assume it's known beforehand, if not we can figure that out too)
4. The Bot tries to post the message

```js
 bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith('!fn')) return;

  const commandFound = msg.content.find(mentioned => mentioned === `!fn ${Username}`)
  const arguments = commandFound.split(' ');
  const userName = arguments.shift();

   if (userName) {
       try {
           await msg.reply(`https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/${userName}/events`);
       } catch (err) {
           console.warn('Failed to respond to mention.');
           console.warn(err);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and tried messing with it aswell but I cant get it to work for some reason. I appreciate your help i have been using https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments to try and understand how to write this bot command but I still cant get it working.

Comment: Check out the other answer it is more generic and might be able to handle your situation. I will try tweaking my answer as well to better accommodate :)